# Number returning NaN?

Tags: javascript, object, nan

I am working with objects with numerous properties and using those properties to draw to canvas.  Some properties I am calculating using the others.  However, I am hitting an issue!

Basically, I have an object with numerous properties and although when I check the type of data stored in the properties it returns "Number", when I call the property I am getting NaN... and therefore I cannot use this when drawing to the canvas element.

So basically, I have this:

```
var MasterObject = {
    Object1: {
        width: Number(document.getElementById("width").value),
        height: Number(document.getElementById("height").value),
        border: 65,
        lines: Math.round((this.width - this.border* 2) / 60),
        lineSpace: (this.width - this.border* 2) / this.lines,
        lineSpace1: this.lineSpace
    }
};
```

The width, height and border properties return "Number" when using "typeof" in console.log() or alert().  When calling these properties I get the number that they store!

Although the property "lines" also returns "Number", when I actually try to call the property it returns "NaN".

The width, height and border, although worked out dynamically, are always a whole integer and I have tried wrapping the "line" property value with Number [i.e. Number(Math.round((this.width - this.border* 2) / 60)) ].

I have also read to try parseInt(), etc, but that is not working either.

I'm sure this is something simple but I can't get my head around what is going on.  Why is the type of data returning Number but the actually data is returning NaN...  I'm confused!!

Appreciate any help.

Comment: what do you think `this` is in the context of your code?

Comment: You might want to give [You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes](http://amzn.to/1Kpc2wT) a look.

Comment: Sorry, "this.border", for example, returns Object1.border.  I have tested this by having a method within Object1 that uses alert(this.border).  When I call that method it alerts the correct property.  I don't know...  maybe my understanding of this is why I'm coming across the problem.

Comment: For example, when using this.height in the same method, it works and draws to the canvas.  It is only when I am calling up this.lines that it isn't working.

Comment: Hint: Create another property as `test: this.width`. Now do a `console.log` for `test`. What does it return?

Comment: thanks guys.  I misunderstood this in the context I was using it.  It's all a huge learning curve and as you can tell, my pen has only just started to draw it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of `this` is not the object in which you're referencing it. One thing you could do is move your code into functions so it *will* be the context you desire, and then call the function instead of the property.

```js
var MasterObject = {
    Object1: {
        width: Number(document.getElementById("width").value),
        height: Number(document.getElementById("height").value),
        border: 65,
        lines: function() {
          return Math.round((this.width - this.border* 2) / 60);
        },    
        lineSpace: function() {
          return (this.width - this.border* 2) / this.lines;
        },
        lineSpace1: function() { return this.lineSpace; }
    }
};

document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = MasterObject.Object1.lines();
```

```html
<input id="width" value="10">
<input id="height" value="15">
<div id="print"></div>
```

Comment: This works.  After posting the question I realised that putting them into the function that drew to the canvas made them work.  I realise now where I have gone wrong. Appreciate you answer and appreciate everyone else's help.  Thanks all!